# different behaviours for double precision on different compiler

Tags: c++, floating-point, g++, ieee-754, floating-point-precision

my code is quite simple

```c
double d = 405, g = 9.8, v = 63;
double r = d * g / (v * v);
printf("%s\n",(r>1.0)?"GT":"LE");
```

and here is my result

- **g++-mingw32-v4.8.1: LE** (the result is EQ indeed)
- g++ on ubuntu : GT ( this result comes from my friend, just do not have a linux at hand)
- VC++ 11 : GT
- C# (.Net 4.5) : GT
- Python v2.7.3 :GT (this also comes from my friend)
- Haskell (GHCi v7.6.3) : GT

g++-mingw, vc++, c#, haskell are all running on my machine with an i7-2630QM

The Python-win32 version comes from my friend, he also gets an **LE** from his g++-mingw-3.4.2.

And the ubuntu version comes from another friend...

**Only g++ gives me LE, and the others are all GT.**

I just want to know which one is wrong, g++ or the rest.

Or what SHOULD it be, GT or LE, in IEEE 754?

Comment: If this is indeed your code (and not a typo) why do you assign a value to `r1` but test the value of `r`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: In fact, it should be neither. `405 * 9.8` is exactly 3969 or 63*63. The fact that conversion to double precision is handled differently in different languages (9.8 doesn't have an exact representation in double) is just a fact of life. If you used `d=4050, g = 98, v = 630;` you would see they were equal.

Comment: Actual answer is `(1 > 1 == false)` so it looks like g++ is the only one the got it correct :-) (by accident). See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I am curious about whether the LE represented a less-than or an equal-to result.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - interesting question. It should be easy for sray to test `r==1.0` and let us know the outcome on his compiler. Based on your answer I am guessing the answer has to be `LT` - unless the compiler is doing something clever and using an "exact" (in the BigDeminal sense of the word) calculation of `d * g` (after all it knows both of these numbers at compile time).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Good question. The answer is `EQ`. I was surprised when I first got the output.

Comment: That suggests that the conversion of 9.8 to floating point and the following multiplication may be being done in Intel 80-bit extended precision. If the 80-bit result of either the multiplication or of the division were rounded to nearest double the division result would be exactly 1.0, and the comparison result would be EQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IEEE 754 64-bit binary result is GT.

The two exactly representable values bracketing 9.8 are:

```
9.7999999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125
9.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125
```

The second one is closer to 9.8, so it should be chosen in the normal rounding mode. It is slightly larger than 9.8, resulting in a product that is slightly larger than would have been produced in real number arithmetic, 3969.00000000000045474735088646411895751953125. The conversion of `v` to double is exact, as is the `v*v` multiplication. The result is division of a number slightly greater than 3969 by 3969. The rounded result is 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

Comment: In addition to the (confirmed here) information that the strict IEEE 754 binary64 interpretation of the program prints GT, since the question is tagged g++, it can be suggested that the OP look at GCC's `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse` options, which should make GCC generate a binary that computes this.

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you have any insights into the algorithm used for converting a decimal to binary? Obviously this is not implemented in the same way in the different languages? Is there a bug report here?

Comment: @Floris Whether there is a bug report depends on the language and compiler specifications. Some languages allow more latitude than others.

Comment: IEEE 754 does not specify a binding from high-level languages to IEEE 754 operations, so it is imprecise to speak of an “IEEE 754 64-bit binary result” for this code. At most, there is a result that is obtained if the indicated operations are all performed with IEEE 754 64-bit binary operations. The compilers that do not provide this result do not violate the C++ standard (because it grants them leeway about floating-point evaluation) or the IEEE 754 standard (because it does not apply).

Comment: @Floris Regarding the algorithms used to convert decimal to binary in different languages, check out my blog "Exploring Binary", and these articles in particular: http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-strtod-works-and-sometimes-doesnt/ , http://www.exploringbinary.com/incorrectly-rounded-conversions-in-visual-c-plus-plus/ , http://www.exploringbinary.com/incorrectly-rounded-conversions-in-gcc-and-glibc/

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from decimal fraction to a binary fraction is precise only if the decimal fraction can be summed up by binary fractions like 0.5, 0.25, ..., etc.

The number 9.8 in your example contains the fraction 0.8, which can not be represented as an exact fraction using binary number system. Thus different compilers will give you different results depending on the precision to represent fractional numbers.

Run your program using the number 9.75, then all the compilers will give you the same result, because

**0.75 = 0.25 + 0.125 = 2<sup>-2</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup>**

So the number 9.75 can be represented exactly by using binary fractions.

Comment: This is not a good explanation. All the compilers that the OP tried use IEEE754's binary64 format for the type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference likely occurs when `d * g` is evaluated, because the mathematical result of that product must be rounded upward to produce a value representable in `double`, but the `long double` result is more accurate.

Most compilers convert `405` and `63` to `double` exactly and convert `9.8` to 9.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125, although the C++ standard gives them some leeway. The evaluation of `v * v` is also generally exact, since the mathematical result is exactly representable.

Commonly, on Intel processors, compilers evaluate `d * g` in one of two ways: Using `double` arithmetic or using `long double` with Intel’s 80-bit floating-point format. When evaluated with `double`, 405•9.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 produces 3969.00000000000045474735088646411895751953125, and dividing this by 3969 yields a number slightly greater than one.

When evaluated with `long double`, the product is 3969.000000000000287769807982840575277805328369140625. The product, although greater than 3969, is slightly less, and dividing it by 3969 using `long double` arithmetic produces
1.000000000000000072533125339280246635098592378199100494384765625. When this value is assigned to `r`, the compiler is required to convert it to `double`. (Extra precision may be used only in intermediate expressions, not in assignments or casts.) This value is sufficient close to one that rounding it to `double` produces one.

You can mitigate some (but not all) of the variation between compilers by using casts or assignments with each individual operation:

```
double t0 = d * g;
double t1 = v * v;
double r = t0/t1;
```

Comment: A compiler that implements `d * g` as `long double` multiplication is as likely as not to interpret `9.8` as `9.8L`, or approximately `9.80000000000000000017347234759768071`. It has the leeway of doing the former without doing the latter, but if its excuse is that it defines `is_iec559` as true and `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` as 2, it has to use a `long double` conversion of 9.8.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: The license of the compiler to use extended precision is for intermediate expressions, not for assignments, casts, or, as I recall, conversion of floating-point constants in source text to floating-point.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf 18.3.3:4 says “The contents are the same as the Standard C library header <float.h>.” C99's 5.2.4.2.2:8 says for FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2: “evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double type.” In addition, interpreting `9.8` as `9.8L` is the interpretation of the standard that Joseph S. Myers chose when he implemented a proper FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2 mode in GCC (which should be available in GCC 2.7 and above with -std=c99)

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Regardless, the code in the question initializes a `double` with `9.8`. The same value results whether `9.8` is converted to `double` or first converted to `long double` and then converted to `double`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: since the expression ought to evaluate to "equal", the test `r>1.0` should be false, and the result printed should be `"LE"`.

In reality you are running into the problem that a number like `9.8` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number (there a hundreds of good links on the web to explain why this is so). If you need exact math, you have to use integers. Or `bigDecimal`. Or some such thing.

Comment: thanks, i know this problem. i have edited my question. i just want to know follow IEEE 754, which result is correct

Comment: Mostly it is the hardware implementation rather than the language that is the thing that will decide the result. Am I right in thinking that these things were run on different machines - with possibly different processors? I doubt that the language has anything to do with it.

Comment: Question updated. Most cases are run on my laptop, I guess it is not cpu's problem.

Comment: @FLoris Processors that provide floating-point instructions at all have been providing floating-point behaving according the IEEE 754 standard for eight years or so. Programming languages, not hardware, are indeed the last killjoys separating us from reproducible floating-point bliss (and after them, math libraries, but the program in the question does not use any library function).

Answer (score -1):

I tested the code, this should return GT.

```
int main() {
    double d = 405.0f, g = 9.8f, v = 63.0f;
    double r = d * g / (v * v);
    printf("%s\n",(r>1.0f)?"GT":"LE");
}
```

GCC compiler sees 405 as int, so "double d = 405" is actually "double d = (double) 405".

Comment: This answer is not helpful. `9.8f` is different from `9.8`.

Comment: what do you mean by "different"?

Comment: “different” as in “if you replace one by the other in a program the program no longer computes the same thing”, or as in `9.8f != 9.8`, or as in question 1 in http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz

Comment: In this particular case, the closest float, 9.80000019073486328125, does round in the same direction as double, although it is a different value from the closest double. In other cases, they could round in different directions, which would change the answer for the code fragment.